# Convert XML to Java with minimal memory usage

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb, moxy

I want to be able to convert a small portion of data in a large XML file to Java, using as little memory as possible.  For example, in code below I want to be able to extract Document with id='3' and it's properties from the XML without iterating through the other Documents.  Can I do this with JAXB alone?  Do I need to use a combination of XPath and JAXB? Should I be using JAXB MOXy?

```
<Example id="10" date="1970-01-01" version="1.0">
   <Properties>...</Properties>
   <Summary>...</Summary>
   <Document id="1">...</Document>
   <Document id="2">...</Document>
   <Document id="3">...</Document>
</Example>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used JAXB in a while but whatever solution is chosen, you will need to iterate through the XML document just to read the data, implicitly with DOM (then maybe XPath) or explicitly with a stream API like SaX (push model, you get the data through callbacks) or StAX (pull model, you get the data by calling methods).

The [JAXB Users Guide](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/) gives the following information in section "4.4. Dealing with large documents", sub-section "4.4.1. Processing a document by chunk". I have added links to the examples on Github. I do not have room here to include everything.

> This kind of XML is suitable for chunk-processing; the main idea is to use the StAX API, run a loop, and unmarshal individual chunks separately. Your program acts on a single chunk, and then throws it away. In this way, you'll be only keeping at most one chunk in memory, which allows you to process large documents.

> See the [streaming-unmarshalling example](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/tree/master/jaxb-ri/samples/src/main/samples/streaming-unmarshalling) and the [partial-unmarshalling example](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/tree/master/jaxb-ri/samples/src/main/samples/partial-unmarshalling) in the JAXB RI distribution for more about how to do this. The streaming-unmarshalling example has an advantage that it can handle chunks at arbitrary nest level, yet it requires you to deal with the push model --- JAXB unmarshaller will "push" new chunk to you and you'll need to process them right there.

> In contrast, the partial-unmarshalling example works in a pull model (which usually makes the processing easier), but this approach has some limitations in databinding portions other than the repeated part.

The `pull-parser` and `xml-channel` examples look promising too. I have made a MWE based on the simple code found in `pull-parser`. The implementation is found at [Eclipse Implementation of JAXB](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jaxb-impl).

```
$ cat source.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Example id="10" date="1970-01-01" version="1.0">
   <Properties>properties</Properties>
   <Summary>summary</Summary>
   <Document id="1">one</Document>
   <Document id="2">two</Document>
   <Document id="3">three</Document>
</Example>
```

```
$ cat document.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

```
$ cat Main.java
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.xml.stream.*;
import static javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants.*;
import generated.Document;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int id = 3;
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("generated");
    Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader xmlr  = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("source.xml"));
    int event;
    while (true) {
      event = xmlr.next();
      if (event == END_DOCUMENT) break;
      if (event == START_ELEMENT && xmlr.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Document") && xmlr.getAttributeValue(null, "id").equals("3")) {
        Document document = (Document) um.unmarshal(xmlr);
        System.out.printf("Text is \"%s\"\n", document.getValue());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
$ java --version
openjdk 15.0.1 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)

$ wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/3.0.0/jaxb-ri-3.0.0.zip
$ unzip jaxb-ri-3.0.0.zip
$ export PATH=`pwd`/jaxb-ri/bin:$PATH
$ export CLASSPATH=.:jaxb-ri/mod/*

$ xjc.sh document.xsd
Java major version: 15
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
generated/Document.java
generated/ObjectFactory.java

$ javac generated/*.java
$ javac Main.java
$ java Main
Text is "three"
```

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at most of those options and they're not really what I'm looking for. The XML document may have a huge list of books and I may only need to grab the very last one. So I want to save time and space to only grab that one, and not iterate through the rest. The other thing is, each book would also have several elements so it's not just as simple as grabbing a single string.

Comment: My example of getting the value as a string is not much more complicated if you have hundreds of lines of XML in the `Document` you are looking for. The unmarshalling process will take care of it. I don't understand your point here. That's why parsers are made for. Concerning your first point, I invite you to do some benchmarking using a streaming API before coming to a conclusion. Even if you don't use an XML parser and just do it by hand, you still have to find the right Document by looking sequentially in the file unless you have additional infos (like an index which you don't in this case)

Comment: Or use a native XML database like BaseX with XQuery, or don't use XML at all. I mean if the file is so huge and you need frequent access, use a relational database e.g, not XML documents. But before doing so, benchmark to get a clear idea of your constraints.